# Use string from filename as column data when reading multiple files with lapply in R

Tags: r, filenames, lapply

I am importing multiple excel files, removing rows and columns, before binding together. I want to add a column, called `id` which is part of the excel filenames. I am having trouble with the line of code to add this column

This is my code

```
library(readxl)
f_path <- "filepath/"
filelist = list.files(path = f_path, pattern = "\\.xlsx", full.names = TRUE)

dat1= lapply(filelist, function(x){
  df = read_excel(x, col_names = FALSE)
    
df1$id = gsub("\\-\\d+\\.xlsx$", "" , filelist) # this is the line causing difficulty. The regex for the gsub is correct.
  
  
})

dat2= do.call("rbind.data.frame", dat1)
```

The error I get is

```
Assigned data `gsub("\\\\-\\\\d+\\\\.xlsx$", "", filelist)` must be compatible with existing data.
```

**UPDATE**

`filelist` has been replaced with `x` as follows

```
dat1= lapply(filelist, function(x){
  df = read_excel(x, col_names = FALSE)
     
  df$id = gsub("\\-\\d+\\.xlsx$", "" , x)
  
  })

dat2= do.call("rbind.data.frame", dat1)
```

But rather than creating `id` as a new "column" (name of item in list) with the results of `gsub` as the data in the column, the result of `gsub` is the name of the "column", so list items can't be binded together

Comment: What do you expect your regex to do? It would remove '-' and all subsequent numbers from the end of filenames in `filelist` but this will never happen because everything in `filelist` ends with '.xlsx'.

Comment: @RobertHacken. Thanks for spotting that. I've updated the regex and the error I'm now getting

Comment: It looks like you might have an extra `"`.

Comment: @dcsuka. Thanks. That's just a typo in my question, not in my real code. Now removed

Comment: You filter rows before the error line, creating something shorter than the filelist. `gsub`ing the filelist creates something the same length as the filelist. Shouldn't the `gsub` line be outside the `lapply`?

Comment: If the `gsub` line is the problem, delete the rest of your code from the question and show us some sample inputs and desired outputs for the `gsub`.

Comment: I think you want `x` in your `gsub` (and `sub` would be sufficient here), not `filelist`. And you should also "return" `df1` afterwards, otherwise only the output of `gsub` is stored in `dat1`.

Comment: @RobertHacken Thanks, I just had figured out that i needed `x` not `filelist`. I replaced with `x` and now get the output of `gsub` as a name of one of the items in `dat1` list. What do you mean by "return" `df1?

Comment: Actually return, not "return". Your anonymous function should return `df1` which it does not now, it only returns the result of its last line. You should add `df1` as its last line.

Comment: Thanks. I was still having problems after adding `df1`, but realised that I hadn't defined the `names()` before creating `df1$id`, which was causing another issue as descried in update. All sorted now